# Can some Stuti mantras give siddhis? Do these verses need initiation & Guru Diksha if they start with OM?

Tags: scripture, shiva, durga, shakti, shaktism

Like the famous "Om Jayanti Mangla Kali Bhadra Kali Kapalini" verses.

> ॐ जयंती मंगला काली भद्रकाली कपालिनी

Answer (score 5):

The quoted verse is from the [Argala stotra](https://greenmesg.org/stotras/durga/argala_stotram.php), a part of the Devi Mahatyam of the Markandeya Purana.

> जयन्ती मङ्गला काली भद्रकाली कपालिनी ।
>  दुर्गा शिवा क्षमा धात्री
> स्वाहा स्वधा नमोऽस्तु ते ॥२॥
>
> Jayantii Manggalaa Kaalii Bhadrakaalii Kapaalinii |
>  Durgaa Shivaa
> Kssamaa Dhaatrii Svaahaa Svadhaa Namostu Te ||2||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 2.1: Salutations to Jayanti (Who is Ever-Victorious), Mangala (Who is the bestower of Auspiciousness), Kali (Who is beyond Kala or Time),
> Bhadrakali (Who is the controller of Life and Death, being beyond Kala
> or Time), Kapalini (Who wear a Garland of Skulls),
> 2.2: Salutations to Durga (Who is Durgati-Nashini), Shiva (Who is Ever-Auspicious and One with Shiva as His Consort), Kshama (Who is an
> embodiment of Forbearance), Dhatri (Who is the Supporter of all
> Beings), Swaha (Who is the final receiver of the Sacrificial Oblations
> to Gods) and Swadha (Who is the final receiver of the Sacrificial
> Oblations to Manes); Salutations to You.

Now, according to the following verse from Vyasa Smriti, Upanita twice-borns (i.e. Dvijas who have received Upanayana Samskara) are already qualified to read Puranas.

> Brahmanas, Kshatriyas, and Vaishyas are called the twice-born. Their
> first births take place when they are delivered of their mother's womb
> ; their second, when they duly accept the Gayatri Mantra from their
> preceptors (21).
>
> **Thus made twice-born, and free from all other faults, they become
> entitled to study the Vedas, Smritis and Puranas** (22).

Therefore it appears that an Upanita Dvija can recite the given Shloka/Mantra without any further initiation. For others I'm not sure.

*(NOTE: It's only a partial answer)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I think this smriti is wrong as most Tantriks have not undergone Upanayana & are using these mantras and getting blessings... Plus smritis are opposed to other scriptures like Puraan, Itihaas, Vedas, Shaiva Agamas & secret scriptures on the rigidity of caste so I don't know how authentic they are??? Anyway do these "mantras" still need to be taken from guru's mouth? Or can we just start reading on our own as if it is not mantra, and just story part of Puraan? These are very powerful mantras after all

Comment: Once one receives Tantric initiation he becomes qualified to perform lot of rites like Tantrik Sandhya, homa etc.. So, they can then chant these Stotras too. I don't think further initiation is required although I currently don't have any reference @R.Kaushik

Comment: Yes that is true "Devi Mahatmya" is known by different names in Tantra and it is supposed to be a 100% Tantrik scripture that was interpolated into Maarkandey Puraan. Do you know if the mantra is sealed? I think Durga Saptshati is locked & needs Utkeelan. Can that mean stuti will be fruitless?

Comment: No, the Argala Stotra doesn't have Kilakam. But before reciting Durga Saptasati one has to recite Kavacham, Kilakam, Argala etc. Otherwise they say the recital doesn't bear fruits. One who doesn't want to go through all this can chant the Siddha Kunjika Stotra@R.Kaushik

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is this information from any scripture? (I think I will have to make a new question haha)

Comment: I have read that in the introduction of the Devi Mahatyam book that I have. Siddha Kunjika Stotra itself states that it does not have Kilakam etc rules and restraints but still by mere recital of it one can get the fruits of reciting the entire Saptashati.@R.Kaushik

Comment: Thank you... I'll dig into Maarkandey Puraan now :')